# REST - What to do when creating or updating a collection of resources if some have been deleted?

Tags: rest

Suppose my server has a collection of employee resources. Also, suppose a client application uses this collection of employee resources to create other resources, or for simplicities sake, suppose I want to update the entire collection of employees from the client application.

What should happen if my client application has fallen out of sync with the server, some of the employee resources have been removed from the server, and then the client application attempts to update a large batch of employees, say, 100,000 or some large number. What should happen to this transaction?

Should the transaction process the good employees and ignore the missing ones, or should the whole transaction fail with a notification to the client as to why it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options.

`410 Gone` can be used to indicate a "404 that was once a resource and will never be again", useful for informing that something has been deleted. The client which received the 410 can then take action.

You can also use the ETags mechanism which provides another flow on concurrency. Every resource should have an ETag and the server can work with headers `If-None-Match` and codes like `412 Precondition Failed` to address how clients are informed about conflicts.

You could just ignore the missing ones and inform the client using a `Warning` header, which can contain more data.

WebDAV (which extends HTTP) has support for batch operations and support returning multiple status codes. It's used in HTTP filesystems which have similar concurrency problems.

Avoid repeating in the JSON response what can be expressed using headers and status codes. The message body should contain only information about the resource, not the transaction.